Ordinal Number not found in DLL
I'd like to start developing a C++ web application with the drogon framework for learning purposes.
I followed the Installation Guide and the Quick Start tutorial from the drogon docs. I'm using Windows and installed the corresponding dependencies with vcpkg.
I successfully created the project with the drogon_ctl create project <project-name> command, made a build directory and run cmake .. from here. The Visual Studio project is successfully built, I can open the .sln file and run the project. But when I try to run the project, I get the error

Ordinal number (186) not found in DLL

and the path for the drogon.dll ("F:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\tools\drogon\drogon.dll").
I already added the paths listed in the Installation Guide to the environment variables. I reinstalled CMake and drogon too, installed all the dependencies.
Does anyone have any idea how should I fix this issue? I can't find anything about this neither in the docs, neither in the GitHub issues. This should be the very first step, I don't even have an index.html file yet.
I also tried to install drogon by source in Windows. I successfully downloaded drogon source, but when I installed the dependencies, I got this output while running the conan install .. -s compiler="msvc" -s compiler.version=193  -s compiler.cppstd=17 -s build_type=Debug  --output-folder . --build=missing command:
======== Input profiles ========
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Debug
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=17
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Debug
compiler.version=193
os=Windows

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=msvc
compiler.cppstd=14
compiler.runtime=dynamic
compiler.runtime_type=Release
compiler.version=193
os=Windows


======== Computing dependency graph ========
Graph root
    conanfile.txt: F:\Projects\Web\kaida\conanfile.txt 
Requirements
    jsoncpp/1.9.4#758827a4d0cb914ad0c03f91e5b4808d - Cache
    openssl/1.1.1t#55e398751ff5310a8525645c99c81495 - Cache
    sqlite3/3.36.0#791ea1c6dc87facb455a40d2531aa088 - Cache
    zlib/1.2.11#8ce05593cbf59d1508deac119de955f0 - Cache
Build requirements
    nasm/2.15.05#058c93b2214a49ca1cfe9f8f26205568 - Cache
    strawberryperl/5.32.1.1#707032463aa0620fa17ec0d887f5fe41 - Cache

======== Computing necessary packages ========
Requirements
    jsoncpp/1.9.4#758827a4d0cb914ad0c03f91e5b4808d:7b737f1649e252dd60b2aefeabe5b6ef5e1a4750#cb36ab4737cab98a1e412bc0c386cfac
- Cache
    openssl/1.1.1t#55e398751ff5310a8525645c99c81495:cdbbe4bac42b20698c46bd5d13465c486c1e3c9f
- Build
    sqlite3/3.36.0#791ea1c6dc87facb455a40d2531aa088:78ef12b339fc837abe48afcbde1a1b5166f528d5#8af70d2cffdbd509bed5a1e960b51830
- Cache
    zlib/1.2.11#8ce05593cbf59d1508deac119de955f0:ed44dacde2751b398e4bf9441ff992a70c913c00#0033e57c9c8aab36ffdedf300928263c
- Cache Build requirements
    nasm/2.15.05#058c93b2214a49ca1cfe9f8f26205568:723257509aee8a72faf021920c2874abc738e029#d8ed631ad7024475859e1b94de1f123c
- Cache
    strawberryperl/5.32.1.1#707032463aa0620fa17ec0d887f5fe41:522dcea5982a3f8a5b624c16477e47195da2f84f#a365b3810f698e2f0a00fbeece022903
- Cache

======== Installing packages ========
jsoncpp/1.9.4: Already installed! (1 of 6)
sqlite3/3.36.0: Already installed! (2 of 6) 
strawberryperl/5.32.1.1: Already installed! (3 of 6)
zlib/1.2.11: Already installed! (4 of 6)
nasm/2.15.05: Already installed! (5 of 6)

-------- Installing package openssl/1.1.1t (6 of 6) -------- 
openssl/1.1.1t: Building from source
openssl/1.1.1t: Package openssl/1.1.1t:cdbbe4bac42b20698c46bd5d13465c486c1e3c9f 
openssl/1.1.1t: Copying sources to build folder
openssl/1.1.1t: Building your package in C:\Users\Zoli\.conan2\p\b\opens95d4b7d49309b\b
openssl/1.1.1t: Calling generate()
openssl/1.1.1t: Generators folder: C:\Users\Zoli\.conan2\p\b\opens95d4b7d49309b\b\build-debug\conan 
openssl/1.1.1t: Generating aggregated env files
openssl/1.1.1t: Generated aggregated env files: ['conanbuild.bat', 'conanrun.bat']
openssl/1.1.1t: Calling build()
openssl/1.1.1t: Apply patch (portability): TVOS and WatchOS don't like fork()
openssl/1.1.1t: gen_info = {'CFLAGS': ['-MDd', '-Zi', '-Ob0', '-Od', '-FS'], 'CXXFLAGS': ['-MDd', '-Zi', '-Ob0', '-Od', '-FS'], 'DEFINES': [], 'LDFLAGS': ['-debug']}
openssl/1.1.1t: using target: VC-conan-Debug-Windows-x86_64-msvc-193 -> VC-WIN64A
openssl/1.1.1t: my %targets = (
    "VC-conan-Debug-Windows-x86_64-msvc-193" => {
        inherit_from => [ "VC-WIN64A" ],
        cflags => add("-MDd -Zi -Ob0 -Od -FS"),
        cxxflags => add("-MDd -Zi -Ob0 -Od -FS"),

        includes => add(),
        lflags => add("-debug"),








    }, );

openssl/1.1.1t: ['"VC-conan-Debug-Windows-x86_64-msvc-193"', 'no-shared', '--prefix=/', '--openssldir="res"', 'no-unit-test', 'threads', 'PERL=C:/Users/Zoli/.conan2/p/straw898fb56546adc/p/bin/perl.exe', 'no-tests', '--debug', '--libdir=lib', 'no-md2'] openssl/1.1.1t: WARN: replace_in_file didn't find pattern '/MTd ' in 'Configurations\10-main.conf' file. openssl/1.1.1t: WARN: replace_in_file didn't find pattern '/MTd"' in 'Configurations\10-main.conf' file. openssl/1.1.1t: RUN: C:/Users/Zoli/.conan2/p/straw898fb56546adc/p/bin/perl.exe ./Configure "VC-conan-Debug-Windows-x86_64-msvc-193" no-shared --prefix=/
--openssldir="res" no-unit-test threads PERL=C:/Users/Zoli/.conan2/p/straw898fb56546adc/p/bin/perl.exe no-tests --debug --libdir=lib no-md2 conanvcvars.bat: Activating environment Visual Studio 17 - amd64 - winsdk_version=None - vcvars_ver=14.3 [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64' Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1t (0x1010114fL) for VC-conan-Debug-Windows-x86_64-msvc-193 Using os-specific seed configuration Creating configdata.pm Creating makefile

**********************************************************************
***                                                                ***
***   OpenSSL has been successfully configured                     ***
***                                                                ***
***   If you encounter a problem while building, please open an    ***
***   issue on GitHub <https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues>  ***
***   and include the output from the following command:           ***
***                                                                ***
***       perl configdata.pm --dump                                ***
***                                                                ***
***   (If you are new to OpenSSL, you might want to consult the    ***
***   'Troubleshooting' section in the INSTALL file first)         ***
***                                                                ***
**********************************************************************

openssl/1.1.1t: RUN: nmake /F Makefile conanvcvars.bat: Activating environment Visual Studio 17 - amd64 - winsdk_version=None - vcvars_ver=14.3 [vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.34.31937.0 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:/Users/Zoli/.conan2/p/straw898fb56546adc/p/bin/perl.exe" "-I." -Mconfigdata "util\dofile.pl"  "-omakefile" "include\crypto\bn_conf.h.in" > include\crypto\bn_conf.h
        "C:/Users/Zoli/.conan2/p/straw898fb56546adc/p/bin/perl.exe" "-I." -Mconfigdata "util\dofile.pl"  "-omakefile" "include\crypto\dso_conf.h.in" > include\crypto\dso_conf.h
        "C:/Users/Zoli/.conan2/p/straw898fb56546adc/p/bin/perl.exe" "-I." -Mconfigdata "util\dofile.pl"  "-omakefile" "include\openssl\opensslconf.h.in" > include\openssl\opensslconf.h
        C:\CMake\bin /                   depend && C:\CMake\bin /                   _all 'C:\CMake\bin' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\CMake\bin' : return code '0x1' Stop.

openssl/1.1.1t: ERROR: Package 'cdbbe4bac42b20698c46bd5d13465c486c1e3c9f' build failed openssl/1.1.1t: WARN: Build folder C:\Users\Zoli\.conan2\p\b\opens95d4b7d49309b\b\build-debug ERROR: openssl/1.1.1t: Error in build() method, line 731
        self.run('nmake /F Makefile')
        ConanException: Error 2 while executing


i think you misread it, it is more like Ordinal number 186 , not order number 186, an definitely not order 66

it is strange that vcpkg would download the wrong version of the dll, are you sure that you are using the correct build type, like x64 release or debug ? maybe you instead configured for an x86 build instead ?

@AhmedAEK You're absolutely right, thank you for your edit! I already tried to install by source in Windows, I attached the output in the post

@AhmedAEK Yes, I'm using the x64-windows type. What's interesting also that I executed the dumpbin /EXPORTS F:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\tools\drogon\drogon.dll command and it's clearly visible that the Ordinal number 186 is here

in the top of visual studio you should see a dropdown with x64 (make sure it is x64) and another dropdown with maybe "Debug" or "Release" or many other things, try them all and see if any of them works.

also i see both conan and vcpkg in your question .... pick only one ! there will likely be version conflicts between them, so i don't recommend using them both in the same project, you will likely need to delete everything they installed and start fresh with one of them only.

one last thing is to make sure you are marking your executable as the start project, in the solution explorer right click on the project of the executable then select something like set as startup project , cmake is known to start at a wrong startup project (though i don't think it will produce that error)
